# Firebase deploy routes not working as they did with npm run (React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, router

When I run `npm start`, my website works as expected on the localhost. I'm able to access the routes that I created, for example:

http://localhost:5000/messages, http://localhost:5000/coaching, etc. all work.

I built this with React Router:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/coaching">
      <Coaching />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
      <FrontPage />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

However, when I use `firebase serve`, or `firebase deploy`, then I'm greeted with a 404 Page Not Found error page whenever I try to access these routes. Only the main http://localhost:5000/ route works. I tried adjusting my firebase.json file to this, but it still doesn't work:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssr"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. Try this 'rewrites' configuration in the 'firebase.json' file:

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }
    ]
}
```